# Trying to convert existing spring app to springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have existing spring app which i am trying to convert to springboot app. Existing app has gradle as dependency/build manager.

So far I have performed following steps:

1. Following dependency has been added in existing build.gradle file

   ```
   dependencies {
       compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.3.RELEASE") {
           exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add an application entry point

## .

```
@SpringBootApplication
    public class MyApplication {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
            }
        }
```

So far no problem in building the project with gradle but when I try to up the project by executing the following command:

`java -jar myapplication.jar`

I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.netspend.partnerconnection.ws.PartnerConnectionApplication.main(PartnerConnectionApplication.java:9)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

I am using gradle 4.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT use `compileOnly` configuration for dependencies needed at runtime (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations) for dependency types explanation)

Use `implementation` configuration, as Spring classes are needed at runtime.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.3.RELEASE") {
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
    }
}
```